# how to make an element forcibly go next to an element

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a div with 100% min-width and it contains 2 table elements.
I used float on the first table to make the second align to the right, the problem is if the first table is too large, the 2nd table will not go next to the first table since the first table occupies more than 100% of the width. What I want is for it to still be positioned next to the first table.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <table id="table1">
     <tr>
      .
      </tr>
      <tr>
      .
      </tr>
      .
      .
      .
   </table>
   <table id="table2">
       ....
   </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
 }
#table1 {
 float: left;
}
```

The problem is, when the table 1 goes over the 100% width, the 2nd table doesn't move next to the table 1.

Comment: Can you edit this and post the code you've used?

Comment: Code, please. Thanks

Comment: sorry, added the sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about text then

```
text-align: right;
```

Or `float: right;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your CSS

`#id_of_2nd_table{
   float:right;
}`

Using float and clear:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you set max width to 50%, that should do it.

```css
table{
  max-width:50%;
  float:left;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```